# How to make image overflow vertically out of div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an image to overflow vertically out of its container, as it is here:

[image: Example of image overflowing vertically]

I've tried setting overflow to hidden, and I read about negative margins but whatever I've tried the image stays in the div.

How can I get this image to overflow out of its container ?

My website is on wordpress, if that matters.

Comment: Not overflow it should be visible, using margin.

Answer (score 0):

overflow:hidden would do the exact opposite of what you're trying to do: it hides what is overflowing.

The image in your example uses 2 separate elements: the div with text and the image, positioned one on top of the other.

You need position: relative for the text div, and position:absolute for the image. Here's an example; the key elements are the `position:` of both divs and the `top:` and `right:` of the second one:

```css
 .text {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white
  }
  
 .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right:25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color:grey;
 }
```

```html
<body>

<div class="text">This is the div with white text on black background.
  <div class="image">This is your image.</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve similar effect using negative margin on the image, e.g.:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
p {
  color: #fff;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero suscipit error ratione neque voluptatum, velit?</p>
  <img src="https://i.redd.it/u9bj2x493pkz.jpg" alt="cat">
</div>
```

Comment: That should work indeed, but there must be something in my theme overring the css, this is what I get if I copy paste your code: 

https://imgur.com/a/hggjROo